# Removing integer from JSON column using JSON_REMOVE

Tags: php, mysql, server

I would like to remove the number 6 from the column `access` (type json) without knowing its array location.

Example `access` row 1: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

---

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    access json NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO `example` (`access`) VALUES ('[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 20, 30]');

SELECT * FROM `example`;

SELECT JSON_SEARCH(`access`, 'one', '30') from `example`;
```

---

The JSON_SEARCH doesn't return any results.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably moved on but should anyone else find themselves in the same position as I, trying to search arrays of integers... `JSON_SEARCH` doesn't support the function.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79233